C++ SOEM EtherCAT; No adapter found - Windows11, Visual Studio+Vcpkg installed Simple Open EtherCAT Master
I have installed SOEM using Vcpkg+VS2022
I have spawned a processes (I assume SOEM would then run headless in it's own process?)
I am able to start the "simple SOEM example", but I cannot get an adapter to be found
I have Wireshark+WinPCAP installed and verified the Ethernet port can have traffic
I added the precompiled option for /WIN32 to get the simpletest.cpp to compile
I did step through the code:
I confirmed reaching "if (ec_init(ifname))", then continued
I found the ec_adaptert variable will take the .name parameter, but then memory gets set back to NULL in pcap.c, pcap_create_common() "p->opt.source = strdup(source);"
the strdup function seems to access windows/pcap functions that I doubt are the problem - not sure what I am doing wrong...
I made it back to pcap-win32.c, sawpcap_create(), but does not call p = pcap_create_common(device, ebuf);
I looked at the device and ebuf values shown in the table
I hit an exception at pcap.c, pcap_activate() when p->opt.source is NULL and checks the string with "if ( (ptr= strstr(source, PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING)) != NULL)" eventually in pcap-new.c
I have tried to call the simpletest.exe via command line without parameters and with eth0 and Ethernet as the desired adapters without success. I think I am very close or nowhere near close.
I cannot test with the drive or run a second PC with SOES until I can at least get one adapter with SOEM. I am not using ROS, just two C++ VS/MSVC projects (parent CreateProcess and also SOEM simple test projects)



var
value




ifname
0x00007ff767bd7460 "\Device\NTPNP_PCI0025"


source
0x000000397953f2a0 "/\Device\NTPNP_PCI0025"  const char *


p
NULL


device
0x000000397953f2a0 "/\Device\NTPNP_PCI0025"   const char *


ebuf
0x00007ff637aea340 ""   char *


device
0x000000397953f2a0 "/\Device\NTPNP_PCI0025"   const char *



I am expecting to see at least one adapter (I have tried with a PCIe NIC and I did not see that either, but confirmed it was fine in Wireshark)
Output from <ECAT_TEST_ECL231.exe>
SOEM (Simple Open EtherCAT Master)
Simple test
Usage: simple_test ifname1
Available adapters
End program
C:\Users\testUser1\Downloads\ECAT_TEST_ECL231\x64\Debug\ECAT_TEST_ECL231.exe (process 15368) exited with code 0.

<SOEMSimpleTest.cpp>

void simpletest(char* ifname)
{
    int i, j, oloop, iloop, wkc_count, chk, slc;
    UINT mmResult;

    needlf = FALSE;
    inOP = FALSE;

    printf("Starting simple test\n");

    /* initialise SOEM, bind socket to ifname */
    if (ec_init(ifname))
    {
        printf("ec_init on %s succeeded.\n", ifname);
        /* find and auto-config slaves */


        if (ec_config_init(FALSE) > 0)
        {
            printf("%d slaves found and configured.\n", ec_slavecount);

            if ((ec_slavecount > 1))
            {
                for (slc = 1; slc <= ec_slavecount; slc++)
                {
                    // beckhoff EL7031, using ec_slave[].name is not very reliable
                    if ((ec_slave[slc].eep_man == 0x00000002) && (ec_slave[slc].eep_id == 0x1b773052))
                    {
                        printf("Found %s at position %d\n", ec_slave[slc].name, slc);
                        // link slave specific setup to preop->safeop hook
                        ec_slave[slc].PO2SOconfig = &EL7031setup;
                    }
                    // Copley Controls EAP, using ec_slave[].name is not very reliable
                    if ((ec_slave[slc].eep_man == 0x000000ab) && (ec_slave[slc].eep_id == 0x00000380))
                    {
                        printf("Found %s at position %d\n", ec_slave[slc].name, slc);
                        // link slave specific setup to preop->safeop hook
                        ec_slave[slc].PO2SOconfig = &AEPsetup;
                    }
                }
            }


            ec_config_map(&IOmap);

            ec_configdc();

            printf("Slaves mapped, state to SAFE_OP.\n");
            /* wait for all slaves to reach SAFE_OP state */
            ec_statecheck(0, EC_STATE_SAFE_OP, EC_TIMEOUTSTATE * 4);

            oloop = ec_slave[0].Obytes;
            if ((oloop == 0) && (ec_slave[0].Obits > 0)) oloop = 1;
            if (oloop > 8) oloop = 8;
            iloop = ec_slave[0].Ibytes;
            if ((iloop == 0) && (ec_slave[0].Ibits > 0)) iloop = 1;
            if (iloop > 8) iloop = 8;

            printf("segments : %d : %d %d %d %d\n", ec_group[0].nsegments, ec_group[0].IOsegment[0], ec_group[0].IOsegment[1], ec_group[0].IOsegment[2], ec_group[0].IOsegment[3]);

            printf("Request operational state for all slaves\n");
            expectedWKC = (ec_group[0].outputsWKC * 2) + ec_group[0].inputsWKC;
            printf("Calculated workcounter %d\n", expectedWKC);
            ec_slave[0].state = EC_STATE_OPERATIONAL;
            /* send one valid process data to make outputs in slaves happy*/
            ec_send_processdata();
            ec_receive_processdata(EC_TIMEOUTRET);

            /* start RT thread as periodic MM timer */
            mmResult = timeSetEvent(1, 0, RTthread, 0, TIME_PERIODIC);

            /* request OP state for all slaves */
            ec_writestate(0);
            chk = 200;
            /* wait for all slaves to reach OP state */
            do
            {
                ec_statecheck(0, EC_STATE_OPERATIONAL, 50000);
            } while (chk-- && (ec_slave[0].state != EC_STATE_OPERATIONAL));
            if (ec_slave[0].state == EC_STATE_OPERATIONAL)
            {
                printf("Operational state reached for all slaves.\n");
                wkc_count = 0;
                inOP = TRUE;


                /* cyclic loop, reads data from RT thread */
                for (i = 1; i <= 500; i++)
                {
                    if (wkc >= expectedWKC)
                    {
                        printf("Processdata cycle %4d, WKC %d , O:", rtcnt, wkc);

                        for (j = 0; j < oloop; j++)
                        {
                            printf(" %2.2x", *(ec_slave[0].outputs + j));
                        }

                        printf(" I:");
                        for (j = 0; j < iloop; j++)
                        {
                            printf(" %2.2x", *(ec_slave[0].inputs + j));
                        }
                        printf(" T:%lld\r", ec_DCtime);
                        needlf = TRUE;
                    }
                    osal_usleep(50000);

                }
                inOP = FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Not all slaves reached operational state.\n");
                ec_readstate();
                for (i = 1; i <= ec_slavecount; i++)
                {
                    if (ec_slave[i].state != EC_STATE_OPERATIONAL)
                    {
                        printf("Slave %d State=0x%2.2x StatusCode=0x%4.4x : %s\n",
                            i, ec_slave[i].state, ec_slave[i].ALstatuscode, ec_ALstatuscode2string(ec_slave[i].ALstatuscode));
                    }
                }
            }

            /* stop RT thread */
            timeKillEvent(mmResult);

            printf("\nRequest init state for all slaves\n");
            ec_slave[0].state = EC_STATE_INIT;
            /* request INIT state for all slaves */
            ec_writestate(0);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("No slaves found!\n");
        }
        printf("End simple test, close socket\n");
        /* stop SOEM, close socket */
        ec_close();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No socket connection on %s\nExcecute as root\n", ifname);
    }
}

//DWORD WINAPI ecatcheck( LPVOID lpParam )
OSAL_THREAD_FUNC ecatcheck(void* lpParam)
{
    int slave;

    while (1)
    {
        if (inOP && ((wkc < expectedWKC) || ec_group[currentgroup].docheckstate))
        {
            if (needlf)
            {
                needlf = FALSE;
                printf("\n");
            }
            /* one ore more slaves are not responding */
            ec_group[currentgroup].docheckstate = FALSE;
            ec_readstate();
            for (slave = 1; slave <= ec_slavecount; slave++)
            {
                if ((ec_slave[slave].group == currentgroup) && (ec_slave[slave].state != EC_STATE_OPERATIONAL))
                {
                    ec_group[currentgroup].docheckstate = TRUE;
                    if (ec_slave[slave].state == (EC_STATE_SAFE_OP + EC_STATE_ERROR))
                    {
                        printf("ERROR : slave %d is in SAFE_OP + ERROR, attempting ack.\n", slave);
                        ec_slave[slave].state = (EC_STATE_SAFE_OP + EC_STATE_ACK);
                        ec_writestate(slave);
                    }
                    else if (ec_slave[slave].state == EC_STATE_SAFE_OP)
                    {
                        printf("WARNING : slave %d is in SAFE_OP, change to OPERATIONAL.\n", slave);
                        ec_slave[slave].state = EC_STATE_OPERATIONAL;
                        ec_writestate(slave);
                    }
                    else if (ec_slave[slave].state > EC_STATE_NONE)
                    {
                        if (ec_reconfig_slave(slave, EC_TIMEOUTMON))
                        {
                            ec_slave[slave].islost = FALSE;
                            printf("MESSAGE : slave %d reconfigured\n", slave);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!ec_slave[slave].islost)
                    {
                        /* re-check state */
                        ec_statecheck(slave, EC_STATE_OPERATIONAL, EC_TIMEOUTRET);
                        if (ec_slave[slave].state == EC_STATE_NONE)
                        {
                            ec_slave[slave].islost = TRUE;
                            printf("ERROR : slave %d lost\n", slave);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (ec_slave[slave].islost)
                {
                    if (ec_slave[slave].state == EC_STATE_NONE)
                    {
                        if (ec_recover_slave(slave, EC_TIMEOUTMON))
                        {
                            ec_slave[slave].islost = FALSE;
                            printf("MESSAGE : slave %d recovered\n", slave);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ec_slave[slave].islost = FALSE;
                        printf("MESSAGE : slave %d found\n", slave);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!ec_group[currentgroup].docheckstate)
                printf("OK : all slaves resumed OPERATIONAL.\n");
        }
        osal_usleep(10000);
    }

    return;
}





char ifbuf[1024];

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ec_adaptert* adapter = NULL;
    printf("SOEM (Simple Open EtherCAT Master)\nSimple test\n");

    argc = 2;
    char testArray[] = "/\\Device\\NTPNP_PCI0025"; //physical device object name of ethernet controller

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        /* create thread to handle slave error handling in OP */
        osal_thread_create(&thread1, 128000, &ecatcheck, NULL);
        //strcpy_s(ifbuf, argv[1]);
        strcpy_s(ifbuf, testArray);
        /* start cyclic part */
        simpletest(ifbuf);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: simple_test ifname1\n");
        /* Print the list */
        printf("Available adapters\n");
        adapter = ec_find_adapters();
        while (adapter != NULL)
        {
            printf("Description : %s, Device to use for wpcap: %s\n", adapter->desc, adapter->name);
            adapter = adapter->next;
        }
    }

    printf("End program\n");
    return (0);
}


I am not sure if the "task spawn"/parent is special, so I attached its code here:
<TaskSpawner1.cpp>
// TaskSpawner1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-processes?redirectedfrom=MSDN
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320781/c-createprocess-failed-code-2

//Expected result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832161/how-to-use-soem-ethercat-master-on-pc-to-control-an-ethercat-slave-device
//I do not see adapter detected...


#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //TUTORIAL SUMMARY FOR SOEM: https://openethercatsociety.github.io/doc/soem/tutorial_8txt.html
    //The following example shows how to add a main function that will be called by startup code.
    // In this example main's only purpose is to spawn a new task that executes SOEM.
    //    int main(void)
    //{
    //    rprintp("SOEM (Simple Open EtherCAT Master)\nSimple test\n");
    //    task_spawn("simpletest", simpletest, 9, 8192, NULL);
    //}

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    printf("Startup Program Location: %s [cmdline]\n", argv[0]);

    if (!CreateProcess(L"C:\\Users\\testUser1\\Downloads\\ECAT_TEST_ECL231\\x64\\Debug\\ECAT_TEST_ECL231.exe",   // Module name
        NULL,        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}

I was expecting to see either the ethernet adapter in the simple test code (or ideally see the ethercat motor slave drive and start working with PDO)

found answer:
vcpkg was not able to play nice with pcap
I was able to see the adapters after installing WinPcap
https://www.winpcap.org/install/
I then used VS2022 using this guide
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-170
then I built the project in VS2022 after opening the folder (VS2022 with cmake installed via the VS2022 installer(checkbox on install prompts)
image should be linked/attached for VS running simple_test.exe within VS2022
to summarize: if using Windows 11 and SOEM, do not use vcpkg to use SOEM, use the official github - https://github.com/OpenEtherCATsociety/SOEM
MAKE SURE YOU INSTALL Ncap instead of WinPcap (WinPcap is deprecated and has security issues and Ncap should come installed with Wireshark now). Select the "Add WinPcap compatibility" when installing Ncap to make sure SOEM operates correctly
VisualStudio simpletest.exe debugging
